# How to re-order data frame based on means and another vector in R?

Tags: r, sorting, dataframe

I have two sets of data frames, the first set is like:

```
df1 = subset(mtcars, select="gear")

head(df1)

                  gear
Mazda RX4            4
Mazda RX4 Wag        4
Datsun 710           4
Hornet 4 Drive       3
Hornet Sportabout    3
```

The format of the second set is like this:

```
df2 = t(mtcars)[1:4,]

head(df2)

     Mazda RX4 Mazda RX4 Wag Datsun 710 Hornet 4 Drive Hornet Sportabout 
mpg         21            21       22.8           21.4              18.7    
cyl          6             6        4.0            6.0               8.0     
disp       160           160      108.0          258.0             360.0   
hp         110           110       93.0          110.0             175.0
```

The row names of `df1` are the column names of `df2`.

I would like to take all the cars that have the same `gear` in `df1` as a group. Then calculate the mean of `mpg` and `disp` together only for the cars, followed by sorting the groups based on their means from high to low.

In this case, the expected results would be (since the cars with `gear 3` have a higher mean of `mpg` and `disp` than the ones with `gear 4`):

```
        Hornet 4 Drive Hornet Sportabout Mazda RX4 Mazda RX4 Wag Datsun 710
mpg             21.4             18.7          21            21       22.8    
cyl              6.0              8.0           6             6        4.0                 
disp           258.0            360.0         160           160      108.0  
hp             110.0            175.0         110           110       93.0
```

I hope this is clear to you. I do not know how to apply the groups (`gear`) of `df1` to `df2` and order `df2` based on the mean of the groups. Thanks!

Comment: I'm confused by your expected output - don't you want your output to have columns that are `gear = 3`, `gear = 4`... etc since you want to treat each `gear` as a group?

Comment: The original `df2` does not have `gear` in it. I see what you mean, it would be good to append a new row of `gear` in `df2` based on the data of `df1` and sort them as groups?

Comment: I dont full understand but suggest use something like `reshape2::melt(df2)` to make in in a similar format as df1. then `dplyr::bind_rows` (or `rbind`) to make it one tall dataframe. Now you can use `dplyr::group_by`  and `summarize`. You might need `reshape2:dcast` to put things together,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I would transpose again `df2` and merge it with `df1`by their `row.names`.

```
tdf2 <- t(df2)
dfmerge <- merge(df1, tdf2, by = "row.names")
```

Then use `dplyr`to calculate mean + disp grouped by `gear`, and also for arranging cars in descending order, from the highest mean to the lowest.

```
m.mpg.disp <- dfmerge %>% group_by(gear)  %>% 
              mutate(mean.mpg.disp = mean(mpg + disp)) %>% 
              arrange(desc(mean.mpg.disp))
```

For finally transposing the data again.

```
finaldf <- as.data.frame(t(m.mpg.disp))
```

To get the data frame exactly as yours, you could use the first row of `finaldf` as variable names, and delete the rows corresponding to `gear` and `mean.mpg.disp` (the mean of the sum of mean + disp).

```
names(finaldf) <- as.matrix(finaldf[1, ])
finaldf <- finaldf[-c(1,2,7), ]
finaldf[] <- lapply(finaldf, function(x) type.convert(as.character(x)))
finaldf
```

The final step I borrowed it from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23209330/how-to-change-the-first-row-to-be-the-header-in-r)

The result (just showing first three columns):

```
      AMC Javelin Cadillac Fleetwood Camaro Z28
 mpg         15.2               10.4       13.3
 cyl          8.0                8.0        8.0
 disp       304.0              472.0      350.0
 hp         150.0              205.0      245.0
```