# How to rename all columns in a dataframe after a specified row, using dplyr pipe

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe, `df` :

```
df <- structure(list(V1 = c("H1", " 0.9", 
"4.1", "4.0"), V2 = c("H2", " 2.174", 
"4.1", "4.1"), V3 = c("H3", " 2.592", 
"3.8", "4.1"), V4 = c("H4", " 2.236", 
"3.8", "4.087463")), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")

> df
    V1     V2     V3     V4
1   H1     H2     H3     H4
2  0.9  2.174  2.592  2.236
3  4.1    4.1    3.8    3.8
4  4.0    4.1    4.1    4.0
```

I would like to rename the columns after the first row, but using a dplyr pipe.

The desired outcome would look like:

```
    H1     H2     H3     H4
2  0.9  2.174  2.592  2.236
3  4.1    4.1    3.8    3.8
4  4.0    4.1    4.1    4.0
```

I have tried this but it doesn't work:

```
df_new <- df %>%
    rename_all(.,df[1,])
```

Can someone suggest a tidy method to do this using dplyr?

Comment: Related pre-pipe answer: [How to change the first row to be the header in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23209330/how-to-change-the-first-row-to-be-the-header-in-r)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `row_to_names` from `janitor`

```
library(janitor)
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    row_to_names(row_number = 1) %>%
    type.convert(as.is = TRUE) %>%
    as_tibble
# A tibble: 3 x 4
#     H1    H2    H3    H4
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1   0.9  2.17  2.59  2.24
#2   4.1  4.1   3.8   3.8 
#3   4    4.1   4.1   4.09
```

Answer (score 2):

Not fully piped but without extra package :

```
library(dplyr)

colnames(df)<-df[1,]
df %>% tail(-1)
    H1     H2     H3       H4
2  0.9  2.174  2.592    2.236
3  4.1    4.1    3.8      3.8
4  4.0    4.1    4.1 4.087463
```

Or fully piped as suggested by @IceCreamToucan & @Henrik:

```
df %>% setNames(.[1,]) %>% tail(-1) %>% mutate(across(everything(),as.numeric))
   H1    H2    H3       H4
1 0.9 2.174 2.592 2.236000
2 4.1 4.100 3.800 3.800000
3 4.0 4.100 4.100 4.087463
```

Comment: You cold use pipes with this method as: `df %>% setNames(.[1,]) %>% tail(-1) `

Comment: @IceCreamToucan, thanks for the hint, didn't think about this!

Comment: You may wish to convert the "`character` numbers" to numeric.

Comment: @Henrik, thanks, you're right, this seems sensible, whereas the example supplied is indeed `character`

Comment: Yes, the H1-H4 row had probable coerced all numeric when reading the data. I suspect the whole issue with double heasders could have been avoided at the reading stage...

Comment: @Henrik, added a mutate in the pipe

Comment: `type.convert` is simpler though (already used above by akrun); check `str(type.convert(data.frame(x = "1.1", y = "1")))`. Cheers